# display message in button click during postback

Tags: c#

Hai frnds , i want to show the message on button click....please help advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

use javascript, set an click event and change the text of the button....

Comment: How do you know this isn't about winforms or WPF?

Comment: @Oded I don't.. but the question is very short and not informative, so I give an answer that is short.. (and maybe not helpful)

Comment: @Erno - OK... but it could be MVC :)

Comment: i m doing some server side validation also in page

Comment: @Rajkumar you want a message on click? so the user sees this while the page is doing a postback?
So set an onclick and then change the text of the button. Don't dare to say this works but something like this
<button Text="ClickMe" onClick="javascript:this.Text='mymessage';"/>

Comment: show message and invisible the message after postback can u help me now?

Comment: ok, you want the changed message also after the postback?
I think you have to set the message from javascript (during click) and set it server side (in the postback code) to have the message after the postback

Comment: how to add the javascript function on button click?

Comment: function DisplaySaveProgress(ctrlIDFirst)
{
    document.getElementById(ctrlIDFirst).style.display = "";
}

Comment: function DisplaySaveProgress(labelID)
{
    document.getElementById(labelID).style.display = "";
}

Comment: this is my javascript function if i call this one in onclientclick its work perfectly but in server side i have one validation if dropdown is not selected it will show message that time i dnt want show this function.any idea?

Comment: ok, you want to display a javascript message but not when the server side check sees that the dropdown is not selected?

Comment: That's not possible, because you can't know in your javascript the result of the server-side check on forehand. An option could be to do the check also in javascript... so both checks in javascript and both checks on your server side.. that would work.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like the javascript client-side handler?

```
onclick="alert('Hi there!')"
```

Comment: client requirment is to show message and it will be invisible after postback

Comment: Then change the text of a label in the page onclick of the button and then on server-side, reset that label so when it loads back in the client it overrides the text shown while it was processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
            <head>
              <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    function message() {
                        alert("THIS IS A MESSAGE!!!");
                    }

                </script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div>
                <button onclick="message()">MESSAGE</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

And you can try JQUERY DIALOG: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnClientClick attribute to specify javascript that will runs before postback request

if you want change text on button:

```
<asp:Button Text="Click me!" runat="server" ID="TestButton" OnClick="TestButton_Click" OnClientClick="(this).value = 'new message'" />
```

if you want show message box :

```
<asp:Button Text="Click me!" runat="server" ID="TestButton" OnClick="TestButton_Click" OnClientClick="alert('message')" />
```

Comment: hai frnds thanks for ur post but small change i want just a message .not alert.

Answer (score 0):

"display message in button click during postback" means i assume OP wants to show message based on condition at server side during click event of button in postback.

this can be achieved using method

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    Type type,
    string key,
    string script,
    bool addScriptTags)
```

see complete code sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx